# Clearing a WkWebview between requests

Tags: ios, objective-c, wkwebview

I have a native segment control that loads predetermined URLs in a *WKWebView*.
What I want to achieve is the *WKWebView* clearing (is blank) between loads.

So right before I fired off the real request, I tried to load:

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"about:blank"]];
[wkWebView loadRequest:request];
```

I even tried to load some empty HTML to no avail:

```
[wkWebView loadHTMLString:@"<html><body></body></html>" baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"about:blank"]];
```

This does work for *UIWebView*. 
Any tips on this one?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible via delegates. Just hide your webview before each request and turn it visible after load completion.

Comment: But there is no delegate callback for when the whole page is loaded. A lot of times stuff is loaded async via JS and the web view has no knowledge about that.

Comment: You can wrapper it using a JS Callback (with JQuery or not) like:
```
$(document).ready(function() {
  Callback.ready();
});
```